# having trouble with the reinstall of windows

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

i recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.
Ubuntu wasn't working good on my laptop so i decided to re-install windows.

**i tried 2 methodes:**

- i created a boot-able USB for windows 8 retail.
  when i tried to install windows it said missing operation system
- the next thing i did was to re-size my partition to get space for windows, when i tried this g parted said that my minimum size was the same as my maximum size.

so eventually i cant install windows.
is there a different way?

Comment: What tool did you use to make the bootable Windows 8 USB?

Comment: i used: linux usb installer(from ubuntu itself pendrive), unetbootin and the normal windows 7 usb/dvd boot

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Windows prior to installing Ubuntu.
Take backup to ext. hdd and delete all partitions. 
Install windows leave Some Unallocated space for UBUNTU.
after successful installation of windows, install ubuntu.

Comment: i dont actually know what you mean.